# How find this sequence such this three condition (AMM Problem 2012)

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Prove that for all $n\ge 4$, there exsit integer $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$ such
following conditions,**

> (1):$$x_{1}=1,x_{k-1}<x_{k}<3x_{k-1},2\le k\le n-2$$
>   (2):
>   $$x_{n-2}<x_{n-1}<2x_{n-2},x_{n-1}<x_{n}<2x_{n-1}$$
>   (3):
>   $$\dfrac{x^2_{n-1}+1}{x^2_{n}}\prod_{k=1}^{n-2}\dfrac{x^2_{k}+1}{x^2_{k}}=1$$

This problem is  from this:http://www.math.sc.edu/~karaivan/AmericanMathematicalMonthlyProblems/11669_BorislavKaraivanov.pdf

and this solution is take a Fibonacci number sequence,I think maybe have exsit other sequence such it,But I can't find it.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: There must be a typo in "$x_{n-1}<x_n<x_{n-1}$" in (2).

Comment: I have edit,Thank you